# HREF attribute with fb comments, ajax load (pushState) and defining href attribute

Tags: ajax, facebook, comments

im really breaking my head with this one, so i hope anyone can take a look and help.

Im buildinf ajax-ed web page with pushState and fb comments. The problem is, that whenever i load new content and fb comments, i get an error about setting the href attribute.
Here is the code:

First, i async call fb init:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId      : 'MY_APP_ID', 
channelUrl : 'http://promplac.si/channel.php', 
status     : true, 
cookie     : true, 
xfbml      : true  
});
};
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

On content change i call:

```
<script>      
function showComment($currentUrl) {
document.getElementById('theplace').innerHTML='<fb:comments id="fbcomment" href="'+document.URL+'" width="510" num_posts="3"></fb:comments>';
console.log(document.getElementById('theplace').innerHTML);
FB.XFBML.parse();
console.log(document.getElementById('theplace').innerHTML);
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="theplace" class="fb-comments"><fb:comments href="" numposts='3' height='150' id="fbcomment"  width="510" num_posts="3"></fb:comments></div>
```

I made an example, i put in console.log the html for comments before and after FB.XFBML.parse() call. As you can see on this example: http://promplac.si/nagradne-igre/nagradna-igra/izberi-oblacila-v-vrednosti-200EUR/

The comments are normaly shown, but when you click on any other entry i get the warning about setting href attribute. But if you check the console, the href attribute is totaly OK? The effect doesnt happen when there is at least one comment...

Any idea what is wrong?